# Insert unique value using Clustered ColumnStore Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, duplicate-data

I would like to know how I would go about of creating my table or choosing an insert that make sure that I do not get duplicate values.

```
create table test.dbo.test
product, 
time,
primary key(product, time)
go
```

When using **Clustered ColumnStore** I can not have any unique constraints to know that the data that has been inserted is unique. Is there another way to check this?

Comment: Since you have a primary key in place, wouldn't sql throw an error if you tried to insert a duplicate key value?

Comment: You can't have a primary key on a clustered columnstore index.

Comment: How about using this info from msdn to create an index: [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589807.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a work-around that uses materialized views.

http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2014/07/24/maintaining-uniqueness-with-clustered-columnstore-index-sql-server-2014/